# Android MVP: Handling all exceptions inside a presenter class

Tags: android, exception, nullpointerexception, android-mvp

I'm implementing an android application in MVP architecture.

I keep a reference to view inside my presenter and do time-consuming tasks such as loading from network inside my model.

My problem is that in each call inside my presenter which I want to call a method of View, it may happen that view is destroyed already and its reference is set to null inside presenter.

So when I received results from model, before each call like `mView.updateUISomehow()` in need to add `if (mView!=null)` since when  control reaches to this point it may happen that mView is null.

I want to know are there any methods that I skip all null checking and handle all possible exception of presenter class in a class-wide exception handler.

**P.S.** I know about MVVM, LiveData and Room. I want to resolve this exact problem :)

Comment: As you already know MVVM would be recommended way, However you want to peruse this! You may create a super class for presenter and it should have a UiUpdate() method which checks is associated view is null or not, so the subclasses of base interpreter class won't have to

Comment: @PankajNimgade Are there any other method or libraries to implement MVVM without using LiveData and Room which handles life-cycles itself? It's strange but somehow I don't like LiveData and Room!! :D

Comment: hahaha, I wish I could say you are not the first person to say that. there are people who have done that but I think it would be reinventing the wheel. However it is possible.

Comment: If you don't like LiveData and Room, you might not like other libraries. but you can try RxAndroid for VM and Realm for database

Answer (score 1):

```
BasePresenter<View>{
  View view

  updateUI(){
   if(view != null)
      callUI()
  }

  abstract callUI();
}
```

Your controller would have the knowledge of `updateUI()`, you may choose how to handle that

```
YourPresenter<ThatElusiveview> extends BasePresenter<ThatElusiveEview>{


  callUI(){
   // hoping this is not directly called from the controller!!
  } 
}
```

I faced the same problem when I was using MVP with too many UI update calls which will happen in the real scenarios. Well did the refactor to Jet pack. I understand your dilemma. 
I believe it is doable if you provide Presenter with listener to view, so if view gets destroyed, Presenter will hold the communication from the controller toward View.

it does sound like checking the view != null, but you can have enumerations of different type of updates going from presenter to View. which you can put in one place to check and then direct them to respective update method depending on the type of enumeration action.
This will also help reading the code regarding different action that presenter is capable of sending to the View

Comment: The problem is I have many updateUI() methods, such as hideProgressBar(), showList(), updateList() and etc. So it is hard to check null for each and usage of super class does not help that much.